# Creating views using multiple rows of data to make comparative selections

Tags: mysql

I have a database which records teams and scores for 7 aside football games.
Teams change every week, but each time a player is on a winning team they are allocated 3 points (1 for a draw 0 for a loss).

I'd like to be able choose a player with ID 21, make a list of the games he has played in, and subsequently give a total number of points and games played together with other players.

I've been creating queries to assess this for the last couple of hours but can't seem to crack it. My process is as follows:

1) list all the games Player 21 has played in

2) list all the Player ID's that have played in the games that player 21 has played in.

3) For each listed player ID above when they appear in any of the games that Player 21 has played in, SUM the listed player ID's total points and COUNT the amount of times that they appeared.

**1) list all the games Player 21 has played in**

```
    mysql> SELECT Game, GameDate, Team, PlayerID FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21';
    +------+------------+------+----------+
    | Game | GameDate   | Team | PlayerID |
    +------+------------+------+----------+
    | A    | 2017-01-10 | A    |       21 |
    | A    | 2017-01-17 | A    |       21 |
    | A    | 2017-01-24 | A    |       21 |
    | B    | 2017-01-10 | A    |       21 |
    | B    | 2017-01-17 | A    |       21 |
    | B    | 2017-01-24 | A    |       21 |
    | C    | 2017-01-10 | A    |       21 |
    | C    | 2017-01-17 | A    |       21 |
    +------+------------+------+----------+
    8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**2) list all the Player ID's that have played in the games that player 21 has played in.**

If I try to run this query with out `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0` I get a `more than one row selected` error.

```
mysql> 
SELECT PlayerID, Game, GameDate, Team 
FROM Teams 
WHERE Game=(SELECT Game FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) 
AND GameDate=(SELECT GameDate FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) 
AND Team=(SELECT Team FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0);
        +----------+------+------------+------+
        | PlayerID | Game | GameDate   | Team |
        +----------+------+------------+------+
        |        5 | A    | 2017-01-10 | A    |
        |        8 | A    | 2017-01-10 | A    |
        |       11 | A    | 2017-01-10 | A    |
        |       12 | A    | 2017-01-10 | A    |
        |       14 | A    | 2017-01-10 | A    |
        |       15 | A    | 2017-01-10 | A    |
        |       21 | A    | 2017-01-10 | A    |
        +----------+------+------------+------+
        7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This lists all the players that have played in the first game/row, with player 21.

Is there some form of `loop` I can put this query into incrementing `OFFSET @X` so that I can get all these games and player ID's listed listed in one table?

This is what I have tried:

```
SET @GameNumber = (SELECT Count(*) FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21');
SET @GameCount = 0;
SELECT PlayerID, Game, GameDate, Team 
FROM Teams            
    WHILE(@GameNumber < @GameCount) DO
        WHERE Game=(SELECT Game FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET @GameNumber) 
        AND GameDate=(SELECT GameDate FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET @GameNumber) 
        AND Team=(SELECT Team FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET @GameNumber);
    SET @GameNumber = @GameNumer+1;
    END WHILE;
```

**EDIT 1**

---

I've got it to a point where I can at least how many games other players have played with Player 21.

```
SELECT Players.PlayerID, COUNT(*) AS Games 
FROM Teams, Players

WHERE 
Teams.PlayerID=Players.PlayerID
AND
(
        (
        Game=(SELECT Game FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) 
        AND GameDate=(SELECT GameDate FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) 
        AND Team=(SELECT Team FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)
        )
        or
        (
        Game=(SELECT Game FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) 
        AND GameDate=(SELECT GameDate FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) 
        AND Team=(SELECT Team FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)
        )
        or
        (
        Game=(SELECT Game FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) 
        AND GameDate=(SELECT GameDate FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) 
        AND Team=(SELECT Team FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2)
        )
        or
        (
        Game=(SELECT Game FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3) 
        AND GameDate=(SELECT GameDate FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3) 
        AND Team=(SELECT Team FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3)
        )
        or
        (
        Game=(SELECT Game FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4) 
        AND GameDate=(SELECT GameDate FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4) 
        AND Team=(SELECT Team FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4)
        )
        or
        (
        Game=(SELECT Game FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5) 
        AND GameDate=(SELECT GameDate FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5) 
        AND Team=(SELECT Team FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5)
        )
        or
        (
        Game=(SELECT Game FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 6) 
        AND GameDate=(SELECT GameDate FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 6) 
        AND Team=(SELECT Team FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 6)
        )
        or
        (
        Game=(SELECT Game FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 7) 
        AND GameDate=(SELECT GameDate FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 7) 
        AND Team=(SELECT Team FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='21' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 7)
        )
)
GROUP BY Teams.PlayerID
ORDER BY Games DESC
;
```

The above give you this table:

```
+----------+-------+
| PlayerID | Games |
+----------+-------+
|       15 |     8 |
|       21 |     8 |
|        8 |     8 |
|       14 |     6 |
|        5 |     6 |
|       19 |     5 |
|       11 |     5 |
|       10 |     3 |
|       12 |     3 |
|        4 |     2 |
+----------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lads, talk about being me a beginner. I was just looking into the `subquery returns more than 1 row` error, and I came across `ANY`. A 3 letter word that makes my life much easier.

```
SET @IDNumber := 21;
SELECT Players.PlayerID, Players.Name, COUNT(Games.Points) AS Games_Played, SUM(Games.Points) AS Points, SUM(Points/Games_Played) AS Points_Per_Game
FROM Teams, Players, Games

WHERE 
Teams.PlayerID=Players.PlayerID
AND
Games.Game=Teams.Game
AND
Games.Team=Teams.Team
AND
Games.GameDate=Teams.GameDate
AND
(
CONCAT(Games.Game, '_', Games.Team, '_', Games.GameDate)= ANY(SELECT CONCAT(Teams.Game, '_', Teams.Team, '_', Teams.GameDate) FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID=@IDNumber)
)

GROUP BY Teams.PlayerID
ORDER By Points_per_Game DESC, Points DESC, Games_Played
;
```